# Heroku, Github and Asp.net core, How to manage appsettings.json?

Tags: git, github, heroku, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

**How can I push asp.net core project to Github and Heroku, but only push `appsettings.json` to Heroku?**

I have tried GitFlow model, Added `appsettings.json` to `.gitignore` in all branches, But one that I named `heroku_app` and configured `--set-remote-to=heroku/master`, therefore Github will not see it as long as I never merge it to branch Github can see.

however this didn't work as intended because everytime I implement a feature to master, then `git checkout heroku_app`, then `git merge master`, A `.gitignore` merge conflict appears, not only that but git removes my `appsettings.json` file.

If only I can set a rule so that never remove `appsettings.json` on `git checkout` or `git merge`, and rule so that never change `.gitignore` on branch `heroku_app`, I would be happy !

Comment: What is your particular reason for excluding appsettings.json from git?

Comment: appsetting.json and its environment specific verisons (such as appsettings.development.json) are meant to be commited to the source code. You should store/set secrets and other sensitive information via environment variables or i.e. key value store (user secrets is only for development)

Comment: @Tseng I have a whole environment specific AppSettings/ folder, but gere I said it's appsettings.json for simplification, If I know how to add rules for appsettings.json, I know how to add rules for AppSettings/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a way to solve the problem I had, simply put I separated production repo and workdirectory repo, then in production repo added two branches one to pull from github and other to push to heroku, then added merge exclusion rules from pull branch to production branch
here is the steps

## === Creating two separate git repos

The first is the workdirectory

The second is the production directory that I create separately

In workdirectory directory:

1. Clone the github repos
2. add "path/sensitvefile" to .gitignore file in all branches, commit and push
3. put the sensitvefile in workdirectory and make sure that git didn't detect any change by `git status

-now the sensitvefile will be ignored, let's go to production repo that I created earlier

1. create a heroku-branch called heroku-prod
2. create a master-branch called master
3. add remote github repo `git remote add github remoteGithubUrlHere.git`
4. add remote heroku repo `git remote add heroku remoteHerokuUrlHere.git`

## === adding merge exclusion in heroku folder

1. add a merge driver called ours in global git config

   `git config --global merge.ours.driver true`
2. add exclusion in heroku-branch

   `git checkout heroku-prod`
   add ".gitignore merge=ours" to .gitattributes
   add ".gitattributes merge=ours" to .gitattributes, then commit changes.

## publishing steps

### 1-  pull from github

`git checkout master`
`git pull github master`

### 2- merge master-branch to heroku-branch

`git checkout heroku-prod`
`git merge master`

### 3- push to heroku

`git checkout heroku-prod`
`git push -u heroku heroku-prod`

## ======= Important Note

any change in .gitignore or .gitattributes will be ignored on merge master-branch to heroku-branch, so if there any change in this file, the change have to:

- Be manually edited.
- Or Temporarily remove merge exclusion in '.gitattributes' file and keep sensitive files away then merge, then return merge exclusion in '.gitattributes'